# Invalidate all other user sessions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing a web site using ASP .NET MVC 4, I use SimpleMembership for authentication.
I need to limit the user to having no more than a specific number of sessions using his account. After the user reaches his limit I would like to invalidate his oldest authenticated session.
Counting sessions may be implemented in global.asax's session_start and session_end methods, but I'm really not sure how to proceed with invalidation. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit late to the party, but here is how i did it.

- When the user logs in, i save the asp.net session in cache
- An attribute (OneSessionPerUser) checks if the user is logged in and his current session equals the cached session

  - If the cached session <> current session --> logout()

I created an Attribute and a static void (for fetching and setting the cache values)

Answer (score 0):

For your problem I would get the keys from the session and then remove the oldest key.

```
 var keys = Context.Session.Keys;  //get the keys
 Context.Session.Remove(keys[0]; // remove first key in the list.
```

Comment: yeah, but how do i get the other user's session?